# web application and BIRT

Tags: birt

I am quite new to BIRT.
I ain't getting any basic tutorial to work with BIRT within JSP.
In my application: 
The customer will send a parameter, with which a complete report will be generated using information fetched from DB.
Can anyone please help me guide to a tutorial?

Comment: Can anyone pls guide me to a tutorial asap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First design your report with your query... if you want a particular name from a table ex:
select * from student_name ..like this u have to design your report after that 
You have to bind your value i.e what name u wanted u just add like this shown below

url = "$report_url/frameset?__report=ur_report.rptdesign&ur_report_parameter="+query
here the query implies that u have structure your query through javascript or by other means like... 
var query = 'where id= '+ur text box id.value ('where id = 1')
in your report u have to add a parameter for this url like(ur_report_parameter)

lastly u have to bind these url parameter from page to ur report parameter for this u have to click on ur dataset and choose script (layout,masterpage,SCRIPT,xmlsource,preview) in that select dropdown to beforeopen and add ur script like this
this.queryText = this.queryText+" "+("ur_report_parameter");
Note : while binding ur query to dataset u have to use (this.queryText) then u will have the result and here u can write ur own javascript...

Comment: Sundar, thank you very much. Can you please guide me to a tutorial? I have designed the report in 'Report Design' perspective with the query already. Also I know how to create JAVA EE application. I don't know to generate the report. What all Jar files should I add to my build path. 
Is there any tutorial which would sufficiently explain the integration of the JAVA EE application with BIRT report?
Please Help.

Comment: No jars needed to your build path ...just create a war of ur report build deploy it separately in ur application server and you can call the war along with the report name/parameter so on....give ur email id i'll send u my report war...

Comment: my email IDs are raghul.mariner@gmail.com and raghul@pointelsolutions.com

Comment: Can you please send the mail to both the IDs.
Thanks in Advance